# how can you Import an os variable into PYTHON and have it update?

Tags: python, linux, import, environment-variables, tcplistener

I'm attempting to find a way to easily and cleanly close my code from an external os input. I have a python tcp server running on a beaglebone black or BBB awaiting a tcp/ip communication telling it to turn on and off a relay via gpio output and it works great, I wrote a windows program to control it remotely. My question is python related and not BBB related. I have this script running for the tcp/ip server interface and when i update the linux environmental variable "pyserv" the script doesn't get the update, it only knows the value of pyserv when the program starts. The trouble code is directly below.

```
    while True:
        pyserv = os.environ.get('pyserv')
        if pyserv == "1":
            server.socket.close()
            break
```

However, before I start the script I can change the environmental variable to 0 and it will run. Alternatively, I can set it as 1 and it immediately closes. If i start the script and then change the environmental variable it doesn't get the update. I've also tried inserting this code into vardata.py and importing the value of vardata.py. I have the same result. Below I have my complete code in context. the problem code is at the very bottom.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import threading
import SocketServer
import os
import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setup("P8_14", GPIO.OUT)
s1 = 0
class ThreadedEchoRequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        global s1
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        cur_thread = threading.currentThread()
        print self.data
        if self.data == "1":
            if s1 == 0:
                GPIO.output("P8_14", GPIO.HIGH)
                s1 = 1
            elif s1 == 1:
                GPIO.output("P8_14", GPIO.LOW)
                s1 = 0
        response = '%s: %s' % (cur_thread.getName(), self.data)
        self.request.send(response)
        return

class ThreadedEchoServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import socket
    import threading

    HOST, PORT = "", 9999

    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedEchoRequestHandler)

    # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
    # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
    t = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
    t.setDaemon(True) # don't hang on exit
    t.start()
    print 'Server loop running in thread:', t.getName()

### This Is Where The Code That Is Giving Me Issue's lies. ###
        while True:
        pyserv = os.environ.get('pyserv')
        if pyserv == "1":
            server.socket.close()
            break
### This Is Where The Code That Is Giving Me Issue's lies. ###
```

Comment: How are you changing the environment variable?

Comment: I'd like to eventually have a bash script controlling everything and running as a background service but currently I'm testing it using export pyserv=1

Comment: Environment variables is not a mechanism for IPC. What happens in every OS is that when a new process is created it gets the env vars copied from the executing process and thats it. You should figure another way to do it, the simplest is creating deleting a file.

Comment: thank you itai, I actually had my script with this line instead. `from vardata import pyserv` and then I would change vardata.py to say `pyserv = 1` or `pyserv = 0` and that had the same issue. It wouldn't respond to any changes I made to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a plain text file to store your pyserv data.

First create the pyserv data file. Eg,

`echo 1 > vardata`

Now run this:

**test1.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import time

def get_data(fname):
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        return int(f.read())

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    pyserv = get_data('vardata')
    print pyserv
```

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to abort the script.

If you change the contents of `vardata` it will be reflected in the script output.

This is simpler (and safer) than storing your parameter in an executable Python file. But if you really do want to use a Python file for your parameters then you need the script to reload the imported data to make any changes visible.

**vardata.py**

```
pyserv = 1
```

**test2.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import time
import vardata

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    reload(vardata)
    print vardata.pyserv
```

Note that you have to do `import vardata`; if you do `from vardata import pyserv` the `reload()` call will fail.

Comment: Right approach. Basically you cannot read updated env from a running process(python script in this case) so you would need to create a new process(reading file repeatedly) that will be spawn with current env variables.

Comment: Thank You PM 2Ring, that was exactly what I was looking for, I actually tried and failed on reload as well and now I know why reload wasn't working. However, after all was said and done I went with the `def get_data(fname):
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        return int(f.read())` method you mentioned to read data from a file. I might change it up a bit later but this works wonderfully for now and I'm able to cleanup before closing the script rather than run a killall and have things stuck in the wrong state.

Comment: @Cfoote7: My pleasure! one cute thing about using the plain file is that `int(f.read())` ignores white space before & after the number, so you don't have to be too fastidious about how you write to the file. But if you want to store multiple items in the file it's probably a good idea to adopt some kind of structuring of the file, eg CSV, JSON or if you're really keen, XML.